# nodeschool.io / makemehapi not working on nitrious.io

Tags: node.js, nitrousio

I try to make the lessons of the makemehapi workshop of nodeschool.io on nitrious.io 
But for some reason I Always get this error message :

```
✗ Error connecting to http://localhost:5548: ECONNREFUSED                                                                                                                            

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED                                                                                                                                                            
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)                                                                                                                                                  
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

I tried to increase the timeout but no luck.

Anyone a idea how to make this work.

Roelof

Edit 1 :

I change this :

```
function verify (port, stream) {

        function error (err) {

            exercise.emit('fail', 'Error connecting to http://localhost:' + port + ': ' + err.code)
    }

        hyperquest.get('http://localhost:' + port + '/')
            .on('error', error)
            .pipe(bl(function (err, data) {

                if (err)
                    return stream.emit('error', err)

                stream.write(data.toString() + '\n');
                stream.end();
            }));
    }

    verify(this.submissionPort, this.submissionStdout)

    if (mode == 'verify') {
        verify(this.solutionPort, this.solutionStdout);
```

to this :

```
 function verify (port, stream) {

        function error (err) {

            exercise.emit('fail', 'Error connecting to http://localhost:' + port + ': ' + err.code)
    }

        hyperquest.get('http://0.0.0.0' + port + '/')
            .on('error', error)
            .pipe(bl(function (err, data) {

                if (err)
                    return stream.emit('error', err)

                stream.write(data.toString() + '\n');
                stream.end();
            }));
    }

    verify(this.submissionPort, this.submissionStdout)

    if (mode == 'verify') {
        verify(this.solutionPort, this.solutionStdout);
```

nothing changes.

Edit 2 : I have looked at other exercises that work perfectly and some of them also work with localhost so I do not think that is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Nitrous servers listen on 0.0.0.0, so you will want to reconfigure your host to utilize that instead of localhost. Once changed then the connection should work.

Comment: Changing 'localhost' to 0.0.0.0 does not fix this error for me.